# Wordpress add product fees to subtotal

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having a problem with the following:

I use "TM extra product options" to add some extra options when buying a product. For example:

Box of chocolate (€40,00)
Extra decorations (extra option) (€15,00)

I offer free shipping on orders above €50,00. The problem is, that the extra fees are calculated AFTER the subtotal, and the shipping is calculated based on this subtotal. In the example above, you still have to pay for the shipping, which i don't want to.

How can I make sure the fee is calculated inside the subtotal (but still mentioned as seperated product) of have the shipping calculated based on the subtotal+fees?

Thanks in advance!

PS:

Something along this way:

`$woocommerce_subtotal = $woocommerce_subtotal + $woocommerce_product_fee;
// set fee on 0 after this line
$woocommerce_product_fee = 0;`

Comment: Can you please post some code of what you tried with your question, so that anyone can help you.

Comment: I would, if I had something functioning, but I am stuck with the basic: how do I even begin to solve this problem. In short, I don't have code yet, since I don't have any idea where to start, or even check if this is possible.